# Sorting a grouped tableview's sections (headers)

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, nsdictionary

I am having difficulty in putting the headers (sections) in a grouped table view in the order I want, which is not numeric or alphabetical order.

Previously I had always added data to my table views by setting up a dictionary and array like this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [temp setObject: AlphaData forKey:@"Alpha"];
 [temp setObject: BetaData forKey:@"Beta"];
 [temp setObject: CharlieData forKey:@"Charlie"];

 self.tableContents = temp;
 [temp release];
 self.sortedKeys = [[self.tableContents allKeys]
                       sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

where `AlphaData` is an array.
Then using the dictionary and array when setting up the table view.

But now I want sections Beta, Alpha, Charlie in that order.

Now I know my issue is because `self.tableContents` is an `NSMutableDictionary` and therefore it has no sorting or index, which I can see with:

```
for (id key in temp) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [temp objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Returns: Charlie, Beta, Alpha. (assuming thats fairly random, if there is no sorting)

So removing `sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];` will not have the desired result.

I have lost track of what I have tried because I have been fiddling and trial and lots of errors rather than really understanding, but it includes altering :

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am feeling a little silly now:

```
[sortedKeys addObject: @"Beta"];
[sortedKeys addObject: @"Alpha"];
[sortedKeys addObject: @"Charlie"];
```

Does the job I need for now.

Apologies.